Laplacian of a function as the limit over the ball
I've been trying to prove the following identity
$$ \lim_{r \to 0}\frac{1}{r^2}\left(\frac{1}{|B_{r}(x)|}\int_{B_{r}(x)} u(y)dy - u(x)\right) = \frac{1}{2(N+2)} \Delta u(x), $$
where this is done in $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ with $u \in C^2(\Omega)$ for the bounded domain we work in.
I've seen the following post, where a similar integral is computer over the boundary instead. I tried to replace
$$ \int_{B_{r}(x)} u(y)dy  = \int_{0}^{r} \int_{\partial B_{r}(x)} u(\sigma)d\sigma dr $$
to then replicate the same Taylor approximation, but now I'm stuck with the constants not cancelling out properly. Is there perhaps an easier way, or am I missing a step?

I'm not used to Taylor series in the multivariable case, but do you really need to be on the boundary to use your Taylor series?

Well, they use the symmetry of the sphere to cancel out some terms in the integral, which I believe you cannot do in the case of the ball. Hence, I tried to reduce it to that case but I'm left with constants I can't cancel out and don't even have the $2(N+2)$ term in there. Maybe I could play around with Green's formula but beyond that I'm not too sure

The post you linked shows that $$ \frac 1 {\vert \partial B_r \vert}\int_{\partial B_r(x)} u(y) \, d\mathcal H^{n-1}_x= u(x)+ \frac 1 {2n} \Delta u(x) r^2 + o(r^2) \qquad \text{as } r\to 0^+.$$ Here I'm using little-o notation, that is, $f(r)=o(g(r))$ if $\lim_{r\to 0}f(r)/g(r)=0$. Since $\vert \partial B_r \vert = n \omega_n r^{n-1} $ where $\omega_n = \vert B_1 \vert$, we have that \begin{align*}
 \frac 1 {\vert  B_r \vert}\int_{\partial B_r(x)} u(y) \, d x &= \frac 1 {\omega_n r^n} \int_0^r \int_{\partial B_\rho(x)} u(y) \, d \mathcal H^{n-1}_y \, d\rho \\
&=   \frac 1 {\omega_n r^n} \int_0^r n \omega_n \rho^{n-1}\big ( u(x)+ \frac 1 {2n} \Delta u(x) \rho^2 + o(\rho^2)\big )  \, d\rho \\
&= \frac 1 {r^n}\bigg [ u(x) \int_0^r  n\rho^{n-1} \, d \rho + \frac 12 \Delta u(x) \int_0^r \rho^{n+1} \, d\rho+\int_0^r o(r^{n+1}) \, d \rho\bigg]\\
&=\frac 1 {r^n}\bigg [ u(x)r^n + \frac 1{2(n+2)} \Delta u(x)r^{n+2} +o(r^{n+2})\bigg]\\
&= u(x) + \frac 1{2(n+2)} \Delta u(x)r^2 +o(r^2).
\end{align*}

On the fourth line, second term, there should be a $2(n+2)$ since you're integrating $\rho^{n+1}$. But thank you a lot! Essentially, I got stuck on your second line due to poor management of the constants.

Yep, thanks :) wrote my answer a little too quickly
